# How can magnetic field change direction, do not changing the velocity of particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, momentum

I know that electron has spin and momentum. Momentum is $vm$ and $v $ is $\dfrac {dx,y,z}{dt} $. So how it could be possible to affect the particle the way it will change only direction, instead of speed? Constant magnetic field does not does work, but when particle moves relative to constant magnetic field it becomes variable, and variable induces an electric field, that should change energy of the particle

Answer (score 1):

> How can magnetic field change direction, do not changing the velocity of particle?

Basically: by acting perpendicularly to the velocity. The force exerted by a magnetic field $\mathbf B$ on a particle of charge $q$ moving at velocity $\mathbf v$ is given by the Lorentz force,
$$
\mathbf F = q\mathbf v \times \mathbf B,
$$ 
and the work that this delivers to the particle over a displacement $\mathrm d \mathbf s = \mathbf v \, \mathrm dt$ is therefore
$$
\mathrm dW = \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf s = (q\mathbf v \times \mathbf B) \cdot \mathbf v \, \mathrm dt = 0,
$$
because the cross product of $\mathbf v$ with any other vector is always orthogonal to $\mathbf v$ itself.

---

On the other hand, some of your other comments require a more careful look:

> when particle moves relative to constant magnetic field it becomes variable

This isn't true. If the magnetic field is constant then it will be constant regardless of what speed you're travelling at. Nevertheless, this

> and [a] variable [magnetic field] induces an electric field

does get at a correct fact: even a constant magnetic field, when seen from a moving frame of reference, transforms into an electric field (plus a magnetic field, of course). However, when you do that frame transformation to the rest frame of the particle, you get an electric field but the particle is at rest, so that the work $\mathrm dW = \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf s =  q\mathbf E \cdot \mathbf v \, \mathrm dt$ is still zero, because in the rest frame $\mathbf v =0$. (And of course if you do a partial transformation, then the explanation involves both factors.)

Comment: Don't understand the last sentence: when particle is in the rest relative to magnet field, magnetic field becomes an electric field? Even if we talk about an electric field (without a magnetic field) You are wrong, because then $F=k\dfrac {q1*q2}{r^{2}} $ _(edited for formatting -DZ)_

Comment: The Coulomb field is irrelevant - the field picture is local, i.e. we only care what the local field is, not how it was made. The transformation of magnetic fields to electric fields is a relativistic effect; see e.g. [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#The_E_and_B_fields) or an advanced-enough EM textbook for details. If you start with a homogeneous magnetic field and you Lorentz-transform in a direction orthogonal to the field, you get a homogeneous electric field (which doesn't have the Coulomb form). This is standard and uncontroversial.

Comment: I thought contracted electric field (in constantly moving particle frame) actually is that called constant magnetic field. No?

Comment: That last comment makes absolutely no sense to me - I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: You've linked me to page, there is an illustration of moving charge field. As You can see when charge moves the field lines contract. But there is a magnetic field lines to, that confusing, because I thought that the contracted electric field is actually what we call a magnetic field. You understand me?

Comment: The transformation properties are general. The illustration is one specific application of those general properties, but it does not mean that all fields look like that.

Comment: Wait a moment, how can force lines be contracted if they propagate with light speed that is constant in all frames?

Comment: @Artur If you're confused about how the relativistic transformation of the fields works, ask it separately.

Comment: Okay but You didn't answered - contracted electric field of constantly moving charge is what we call magnetic field?

Comment: "Contracted electric field" is a misleading term that shouldn't be used - and no, it isn't what we call magnetic fields.

Comment: Comment threads are not for extended back-and-forth - take it to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (once you have [enough reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)). I won't be answering any more questions in this thread that are not directly related to this answer.